# Concat Constant in php

Tags: php

```
namespace my;

const DHA=__NAMESPACE__."you are accessing constant";  //generate parse error

const DHA=__NAMESPACE__,"you are accessing constant";  //generate parse error
```

I tried concating using '.' and ','  but both it gives

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';'**

**EDIT (UPDATE) :** This is a bug in PHP 5.5. It has been resolved in 5.6. https://wiki.php.net/rfc/const_scalar_exprs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of PHP

See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42355

Considered a new feature in 5.6

I have 5.5.9 right now and get the same results as you do

Comment: Thank you. I did not know this i a bug. I tried various article for last two days but did not get help. finally i thought to put it on Stackoverflow.
Yes i am using 5.5 because.

Comment: @Curious Yes supposed to be in 5.6 but I have not tested on that